# Jqgrid Custom buttom in Navigation pager that creates custom dialog

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to code a custom button in the navigation bar in Jqgrid(I'm new to JqGrid). Its function is simple... based on the selected row, it has to get some info from the server and then opens a dialog with the info requested.

Here we go:

```
           .navButtonAdd('#pager-list',{
            caption: "",
            title: "View products", 
            buttonicon:"ui-icon-clock",
            onClickButton : function () { 

                    var line = $('#grid-list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                    if ( line == null ) {
                        alert("please select a row!");
                    }
                    else {

                        $.get('products.php', { rowSel: line }, function ( data ) {






      I want to implement a dialog that will open and set something(using the JSON response from server DATA). 
         like this very simple:
    Product ID: data[0].pID;
    Product Name: data[0].pName;
    Product Price: data[0].pPrice;

and a close button.


                         });

                   }


            },
```

I have seen a couple examples but I just got confused. Could anybody help me with this coding... Thanks in advance.

UPDATE...I solved Like this:

```
else {



                        $.get('products.php', { rowSel: line },
                       function ( data ) {

                        $.jgrid.info_dialog('Review Products',data, $.jgrid.edit.bClose,{buttonalign:'center', width:'auto',resize: true , align: 'left'});


                        });
```

All the data manipulation has been made at server side...

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I came across with the same situation some time ago, where I wanted to add a button to download the selected rows from jqgrid in a csv format. But I found it much easier to put a button outside the grid and do an ajax request to the server and get a result. Actually in my case it was a synchronous call. Anyways..here is the code I used..I am not saying its impossible but it depends on your project restrictions...:

```
    function x() {

     var obj = jQuery("input:checked").map(function() { return jQuery(this).parents('tr').attr('id'); });

    var result = null;
    var arr = jQuery.makeArray(obj);
    var data = arr.join(',');

   $.ajax({
     url : '<%= url_for :controller => "products", :action =>"export_to_csv" %>',
         type : 'POST',
     data : {data:data},
     dataType : 'string',
         async: false,
         success : function(response) { result = response; }
     }); 

    window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(result));

     };

    <%= jqgrid("List of products: you can filter (using the lens icon in the bottom of the grid), sort (clicking on the header column), scroll the data in the grid (using the pagination system)", "gbgrid", products_path,
  [{ :field => "id"},{ :field => "act"},{ :field => "code"}]
      }) %>
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont know about the codes on LuferBRA but I came across the same issue with JQgrid and I had prob with the AJAx request...I guess synchronous request is the solution. Thanx Kumar